# How to update files using Axios and React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, form-data

I've built an api with posts/articles, and now I'm working on the front end. I'm having an issue with uploading a new photo for an already existing post. I've attempted the two most common methods for the photo, formData and JSON Base64. I'm receiving the same error response for both methods, `Please upload a file, code: 400`. I'm not certain where I've gone wrong, so I'll provide every relevant file.

**articles.js(server)**

```
exports.articlePhotoUpload = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const article = await Article.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!article) {
        return next(
            new ErrorResponse(`Article not found with id of ${ req.params.id }`, 404)
        );
    }

    //Make sure user is article owner || make sure user is admin
    if (article.user.toString() !== req.user.id || req.user.role !== 'admin') {
        return next(
            new ErrorResponse(
                `User ${ req.user.id } is not authorized to update this article`,
            )
        )
    }

    if (!req.files) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please upload a file`, 400))
    }

    const file = req.files.file;

    // Confirm the image is a photo
    if (!file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please upload an image file`, 400))
    }

    // Check File Size
    if (file.size > process.env.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD) {
        return next(
            new ErrorResponse(`Please upload an image less than ${ MAX_FILE_UPLOAD }`, 400)
        )
    }

    // Create custom filename
    file.name = `photo_${ article._id }${ path.parse(file.name).ext }`;

    file.mv(`${ process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH }/${ file.name }`, async err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            new ErrorResponse(`Problem with file upload`, 500);
        }

        await Article.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { photo: file.name });

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: file.name
        });

    });

});
```

^the above function is where the error message is triggered server-side.

**axios.js(client-side)**

```
...
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://<<ip address>>/api/v1';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth');
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';


export const uploadPhoto = (id, data) => {
    return axios.put(`/articles/${ id }/photo`, {
        data
    })
}
...
```

^I have a feeling I could format this exported function better. I might be missing something here.

**UploadPhoto.jsx(JSON Attempt)**

```
const UploadPhoto = (props) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const { state } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [filename, setFilename] = useState(null);

    const onSubmit = async () => {
        const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
            console.log(reader.result)
        });

        const data = {
            title: filename,
            file: await toBase64(file),
        }

        uploadPhoto(`5ea5e73044718d0b2c2ae5df`, data)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.error))
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <h2>Cover Image</h2>
            <label>
                Select A File:
            </label>
            <img id="image" src="" alt="" />
            <input
                type="file"
                name="photo"
                ref={register}
                defaultValue={state.data.photo}
                onChange={handleChange}

            />
            <label htmlFor="">
                Filename
            </label>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    )
}

export default withRouter(UploadPhoto);
```

**UploadPhoto.jsx(formData attempt)**

```
const onSubmit = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        console.log(file)

        uploadPhoto(`5ea5e73044718d0b2c2ae5df`, formData)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.error))
    }
```

This is my first time building my own api, which is why I put the server code in here. However, I'm 90% sure I'm making a mistake client-side, most likely in the axios.js file.

Comment: Could it be that your server (I assume you use express) does not make use of the body-parser middleware and thus `req.files` is always `undefined`? It seems to run into this code branch. Edit: If you are posting the file as multipart, you might even need a module that is able to parse that, such as multer.

Comment: I'm using body parser in the server file of the api, initialized as `app.use(express.json());`. I just noticed that in other examples when the file in question is console.loged the file size appears in parentheses like so `File(182272)` while mine doesn't. It's just `File {}` with the full object inside. Could this be a matter of scope?

Comment: The statement `express.json()` only returns a body-parser that will extract a JSON-body from the request. You need a special middleware reading files. What you observed just tells you that file is empty because nothing has been parsed yet.

Comment: Okay. I'll see if I can use multer server-side to keep the client as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this example:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

// enable files upload -- this should also make 'req.files' accessible
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true
}));
```

Add this in the beginning of your server initialization. After that your normal code should try accessing `req.files` as it should be filled on file upload requests now.
You will need to install module express-fileupload before using it in code -> `npm i express-fileupload`

(Source: https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express)

Comment: I actually have express-fileupload in my server.js file. I didn't use createParentPath though. This might be it.

Comment: So I followed the article you linked to me step by step, while testing each time I made a change. I'm still getting the same error response. I made a for loop to console.log the formData and noticed the following `file, [object File]`. Is it supposed to show up like that? I'm also considering some other things that could be affecting this. 

Does it matter that the uploads folder is in the server and not the client?
Does it make a difference that the image is labeled 'photo' in the model?

Comment: Correction: everything works fine in postman pre and post changes